# Bad Request (400) in django web app in Azure App service while adding Custom Domain

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

In the Azure app service
my Website is working fine with something.azurewebsites.net with the following code

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ['WEBSITE_HOSTNAME']] if 'WEBSITE_HOSTNAME' in os.environ else []
```

But while adding a custom domain, it is showing as Bad Request (400). I think the problem relies on the Allowed host, and the Django app is not allowing my custom domain. I couldn't find a solution or a perfect line of code to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you added ALLOWED_HOSTS argument in the settings. Configure () section in your code? If not please add try the same.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion! I added ALLOWED_HOSTS to the application configuration. And with some additional changes in the code, it is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ['WEBSITE_HOSTNAME'],os.environ['CUSTOM_HOSTNAME']]
```

CUSTOM_HOSTNAME should be added to the application configuration in azure.

Eg: CUSTOM_HOSTNAME: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the custom domain in Azure? To do this, you can follow the steps in the Azure documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-dns-web-site#map-a-custom-dns-name-to-an-azure-web-app

This will involve adding a CNAME record for your custom domain that points to your Azure app's default domain.